# exclude duplicate groups of rows given grouping variable

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3], 'B':[5,6,7,5,6,7,8,5,6,7], 'C':['x','x','x','y','y','y','y','z','z','z']})
```

I'm trying to get rid of duplicate groups of rows when considering grouping variable `C`.

In my example, only `x` and `z` are duplicates, because y has an extra row that makes it different from `x`.

So the output should be:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  5  x
1  2  6  x
2  3  7  x
3  1  5  y
4  2  6  y
5  3  7  y
6  4  8  y
```

the methods I tried (`.duplicated`, `.drop_duplicates`) seem to work well when comparing single rows, but not group of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case we can `groupby` with `tuple` first

```
out = df.loc[df['C'].isin(df.groupby('C').agg(tuple).drop_duplicates().index),]
Out[13]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  5  x
1  2  6  x
2  3  7  x
3  1  5  y
4  2  6  y
5  3  7  y
6  4  8  y
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using [`pandas.util.hash_pandas_object`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.util.hash_pandas_object.html) to compute a hash of each group.

```
idx = (df.drop(columns='C')
         .groupby(df['C'])
         .apply(lambda g: pd.util.hash_pandas_object(g, index=False).agg(tuple))
         .drop_duplicates().index
        )

out = df[df['C'].isin(idx)]
```

output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  5  x
1  2  6  x
2  3  7  x
3  1  5  y
4  2  6  y
5  3  7  y
6  4  8  y
```

It is more verbose than the nice and short code of @BENY but significantly more efficient on many columns.

Timing on 400 columns:

```
# dataframe hash
54.5 ms ± 3.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# tuple aggregation
255 ms ± 22.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```